# How to use RegExp in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to use `RegExp` in `else if(){}` statements. How is it done?

I want to do:
**If the user's value (prompt) is equal to `"javascript"` or `"JaVaScRipT"` then let the `else if` statement work.**

```html
<body>
    <button onclick="javascript:notfic();">Click</button>
    <p id="result"></p>

    <script>
        "use strict"
        function notfic(){
            let message="", result, del;
            result = document.querySelector('#result');

            del = prompt("Please, enter your answer");
           if (del == null || del==""){
               message = "You must write answer";
           }else if(del == /javascript/i){
             message = "You enter correct answer. Your answer is: <br> " + del;
           }else{
               message = "Sorry, your answer is wrong. Your answer is: <br>" + del;
           }
            result.innerHTML = message;

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: To test a regex you can use the [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method instead of the `==`

Comment: `del == /javascript/i` compares del with a regex, but del is a string, not a regex ... `/javascript/i.test(del)` is possibly better

Comment: You don't need regex for this. Just compare after converting the input to lowercase e.g. `if (del.toLowerCase() === 'javascript') { // do the stuff }`

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> [Regular expressions - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Thanks, guys! You are hero! hehe <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your you need to call the `test` method:

```js
else if(/javascript/i.test(del))
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for more info